# Overlaying base plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, viewport

I have a paleogeographic map drawn using base graphics such as this:

[image]

And I have ggplot2 plot drawn in the same coordinate system:

[image]

I would like the second plot to be drawn on top of the first map and that the legend of line lenghts would be below the first map. The result should look something like this (everything drawn using base graphics):

[image]

How to do it?

Analogical case would be to draw "X" sign by drawing one line using base graphics and the other line using ggplot2:

For example:

```
#base line
plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),axes=F,type = "l",ann = F) 

#ggplot2 line
ggplot(data.frame(X=c(0,1),Y=c(1,0)),aes(X,Y)) + 
geom_path() +
theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
axis.text.x=element_blank(),
axis.text.y=element_blank(),
axis.ticks=element_blank(),
axis.title.x=element_blank(),
axis.title.y=element_blank(),
legend.position="none",
panel.background=element_blank(),
panel.border=element_blank(),
panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
plot.background=element_blank())

#Desired visual output
plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),axes=F,type = "l",ann = F)
lines(data.frame(X=c(0,1),Y=c(1,0)))
```

Comment: and why do you don't use your third plot....looks like your desired result IMO ;) But have a look here and plot everything with ggplot  https://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html Provide full reproducible data for more help

Comment: I'm not familiar with maps in plots, but I'm fairly sure there must be ggplot2 extension packages that allow you to plot maps as a ggplot2 layer. Have you tried searching tutorials and packages for how to plot maps in ggplot2? This might help you get started: https://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html

Comment: I don't use the third plot, because I have built special function using ggplot2 for my data type. This function draws lines of certain width (in mm) and adds fancy labels to these lines, as well as precise legend of line widths. As far as I know, in base graphics line width is expressed in units relative to device size, not absolute size units like mm.  Thanks for the link.